# Unable to grant privileges to user in mysql

Tags: mysql, user-accounts, privileges

For some reason, I've had all of my privileges revoked on my user account for MySQL. I can't even allow myself to reset any of my privileges. I also don't have root access, so I feel I'm in a deadlock. I haven't tried reinstalling it, but I have read that it wouldn't really work here.

[image: privileges]

Answer (score 0):

So I uninstalled MySQL and deleted every folder related to it, and then reinstalled it, which allowed me to reset my privileges.